# set a array in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I would like to set an array in an where clause.

```
function rapport_detail_opbrengsten($idKlant){
            $this->db->from('Project');
                $this->db->join('Opbrengsten', 'Opbrengsten.idProject = Project.idProject');
if ($idKlant > 0){
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);}
         $query = $this->db->get();
         $project = array();
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $project[] = $row->idProject;
            }
            return implode("`,`", $project);
                $this->db->select('idProject, SUM(Prijs) as total'); 
                $this->db->from('Opbrengsten');
                $this->db->where_in('idProject', $project);
                $this->db->group_by('idProject');
                $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
         }
        else{
             return false;
         }
     }
```

The return gives the following: `string(66) "7`,`14`,`14`,`81`,`81`,`81`,`14`,`9`,`15`,`11`,`12`,`6`,`6`,`6`,`6"

But somehow this doesnt work in the where_in or the where clause.

Comment: Why are you using return statement in the middle of the code?

Comment: Because i need to get the returned value to use in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

you are miss using backticks there you need quotes.Change your `where_in()` to

```
$this->db->where_in("idProject",$project);
/* $project should be an array containing list of ids not a string */
```

According to [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) in `where_in()` you can pass array of values in second argument

Or just use `where()`

```
$this->db->where("idProject IN('".join("','",$project)."')",FALSE);
```

Comment: then i get bool (false) when i dump the var.

Comment: @Rene see my updated answer and be precise to mention which example isn't working